# A href links not clickable or highlightable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not completely sure as to why my a href links aren't working...At one point in time it was working, I did some research on the Z-Index but that doesn't seem to be the problem, nor do I have an overlapping div.

**Please visit the [JSFIDDLE.NET](https://jsfiddle.net/t9v7obtq/) for the demo**.

```
<nav class="navbar-default">
    <div class="util-bar-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/util-bar-logo.png" /></a> </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li>
                        <p style="margin-top: 6px; max-height: 36px;">1(800) 000 - 0000</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 8px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    height: 36px;
}.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    height: 36px;
}.navbar {
    min-height: 36px !important;
}
```

I'm using the BootStrap Framework.

Comment: Can we have some more code relating the other divs because on its own your nav is working find. https://jsfiddle.net/qokaeu8v/

Comment: Here is the fiddle link of your code - https://jsfiddle.net/t9v7obtq/ . Links are working perfectly. Please be little more specific with what exact problem that you are facing.

Comment: @Mathew Hammond - Which ones specifically? util-bar-content is just an empty div.

Comment: @xXTheAwesomerXx can you please include the content section as at the moment I can't work out the problem as the links are working fine on its own, so it must be there other html or css which are causing the issues.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript around this code? You could be preventing the click event from navigating via JavaScript. Since all of your links point to # are you handling the click event with code or have you removed the actual links?

Comment: http://fixedminds.com/dev/ The site is hosted there, the CSS and HTML is there. I'm not entirely sure on which divs you guys want me to post. Sorry if I seem like I just knocking it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your give your links a class of link and then set that class to have a z-index of 9999;

Example:

```
<li>
<a class="links" href="#">About</a>
</li>

.links {
z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot! I guess I don't understand z-index well.

Comment: @xXTheAwesomerXx haha nether do I :) I just played around until it worked! Glad it worked, anymore help just post a new question and send me a link here and i will try and help

Comment: That's the development world for you haha